# Method 'get_Lookups' in type 'Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbDataAdapterProvider'

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-analytics

This is the error we get.

```
Method 'get_Lookups' in type 'Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbDataAdapterProvider' from assembly 'Sitecore.Analytics.MongoDB, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.
```

This happened after 7.5 upgrade to 8.2.3. Upgrade went well and website works, now when we try to enable analytics in Sitecore.Xdb.config. and then this error.

Stack Trace:

```
[TypeLoadException: Method 'get_Lookups' in type 'Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbDataAdapterProvider' from assembly 'Sitecore.Analytics.MongoDB, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName) +95
   System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +53
   System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +44
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateType(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +109
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +69
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +163
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, Boolean assert) +68
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetProviders(List`1 nodes) +348
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetProviders(String rootPath, TProvider& defaultProvider) +356
   Sitecore.Configuration.ProviderHelper`2.ReadProviders() +75
   Sitecore.Configuration.ProviderHelper`2.get_Provider() +131
   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.ContactRepository..ctor() +48

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +438
   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CreateObject(Type type, Object[] parameters) +119
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +117
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +163
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +72
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +615
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromReference(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +170
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +116
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +72
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetInnerObject(XmlNode paramNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +109
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred, IFactoryHelper helper) +554
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +320
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +72
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +615
   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeAutomation.Process(PipelineArgs args) +72
   (Object , Object[] ) +71
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +479
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Application_Start() +258
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +673
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +583
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +169
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +396
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +333

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +525
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +124
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +700
```

Comment: Can you make sure that the correct sitecore mongodb dlls are updated properly. I would suggest to install a fresh sitecore instance locally and compares the dlls

Comment: Sitecore.stackexchange.com is dedicated site for Sitecore related questions, try to use it for any new question.